# Keras - ValueError: If steps_per_epoch is set, the `batch_size` must be None

Tags: deep-learning, keras

No mention of such an incompatibility in the [doc](https://keras.io/models/sequential/). What I want to do is declare a number of batches (of fixed given size) to be processed before ending an epoch and starting the next one (shuffling beforehand) in order to try to reduce overfitting. When I chose `batch_size=256` and `steps_per_epoch=100` it raises:

```
ValueError: If steps_per_epoch is set, the `batch_size` must be None.
```

Is there a workaround in Keras 2.1.2 ?

Here is the related code:

```
model.fit(xtrain, ytrain,
          batch_size=256,
          epochs=100,
          callbacks=get_callbacks(patience=10),
          validation_data=(xval, yval),
          class_weight=get_class_weight_trainset(ytrain),
          steps_per_epoch=100)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of combining batch_size and steps_per_epoch? It just seems you want to set batch_size only.

Comment: If I fixe batch_size and not steps_per_epoch, the network will train on the same dataset (but shuffled) for every epoch. What I would like to do is to select, say 50%, of the training set at each epoch so that the network learns on "multiple" datasets (in terms of distribution and such) at each epoch. A bit like an ensemble method, except on the dataset and not on models.

Comment: Unfortunately you are not going to achieve that with any model.fit parameters, it is something you would have to implement manually and call fit for each sample of the dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fit` function assumes that the total number of training samples is fixed, there is no need to specify both `batch_size` and `steps_per_epoch`.

To achieve your goal, I suggest you to take a look at [`train_on_batch` function](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#train_on_batchco)

Comment: Thanks you! I wasn't aware that we could control the training with Keras.